# Facebook follow button not updating layout and faces option

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am using following JS function which is called whenever user change profile URL, show face option, layout option.

It updated data-href but don't know why it's not updating data-layout and data-show-faces options. Both layout and faces variables are correct than what I'm missing?

```
function wpfollow_func() {
var faces = jQuery('#facey').is(':checked');
var layout = jQuery('input[name=layout]:checked').val();
if (faces) {
    faces = true;
} else {
    faces = false;
}

var url = jQuery('#profile').val();
console.log(layout);
if (url == '' || url == null) {
    url = 'https://www.facebook.com/zuck';
}

var token = url.indexOf('http://');
if (token == -1) {
    token = url.indexOf('https://');
}
if (token == -1) {
    url = 'http://' + url;
}
var data = '<div class="fb-follow" data-href="' + url + '" data-layout="'+ layout +'" data-show-faces="' + faces + '"></div>';
console.log(data);
jQuery('#u_0_18').html(data);
console.log(token);

FB.XFBML.parse();
return false;
}
```

Comment: faces should already be a boolean, so not sure why you are setting it to true and false again.

Comment: @epascarello i want when user select hide face/show face, button should change accordingly like happening here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/follow-button, that's why I'm setting it true or false and passing it. how can I achieve this without this method?

Comment: My point is jQuery [is method](http://api.jquery.com/is/) already returns a Boolean!

Comment: oh sorry, i got your point! but why it is not updating facebook button settings? it is updating if i change URL, what should I do so that it also update on face checkbox change and layout option change?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but it could be because of how the faces are loaded from the JS SDK. If it is the only thing that is not updating I would say that's the problem.